# PS4 motion detection usage

Tags: controllers, battlefield-1

I just bought a PS4 and cannot figure out how to use the gyroscope/accelerometer in Battlefield 1. Is there a use for it in this game? How can I enable this feature?

Comment: Is there a game in particular you are asking about?

Comment: Yes, new [BF1](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/games/battlefield-1-ps4/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Battlefield 1 but normally games that support the controller accelerometer will use it by default.
However if the game is mean to be played in a traditional way (i.e. without accelerometer) but the game supports it, then you normally can enable it in the options of the game itself. Take a look in options and see if there is any section called controls or something similar.
If you can't find anything most likely this game is not supporting it. But again I'm not familiar with Battlefield 1 in particular.